# Mariadb query utf8 escaped string

Tags: mysql, utf-8, mariadb

I am using  5.5.65-MariaDB MariaDB Server.

I have a table with a column of type medium text, named "remoteData", where I store a json string.
String values in this json string are stored as escaped utf8 sequences, for example

```
"patientFirstName":"\u0395\u039b\u0395\u03a5\u0398\u0395\u03a1\u0399\u039f\u03a3"
```

The above value is the Greek Name "ΕΛΕΥΘΕΡΙΟΣ".

I am trying to search this column using the query

```
Select * from sync_details where remoteData like "%ΛΕΥΘΕΡ%"
```

but I get an empty set.

I assume this is because of the values being escaped but I don't know what to do.

EDIT: The query will run through php so we can use a solution that includes php functions.

Thank you in advance.

Christoforos

Comment: to allow all character set you can use `utf8mb4`

Comment: Both in the database connection and as the datatype for remoteData in the sync_detauls table.

Comment: What is the character set defined for the table? What I'm getting at is whether the database is holding an ASCII sequence  beginning with the six character sequence "\u0395" orif this is being written to the database as a single utf8 character. What is the character set you are using for your connection?

Comment: @symcbean   character set is utf8_general_ci.  It is used on many other tables with no problem. The difference here as I mentioned is that the data stored are already in the form \u0395

Comment: @aRvi I use utf8_general_ci which contains all the characters for english and greek language that I use. this is not the problem.

Comment: @danblack sorry I don't understant

Comment: I don't think MySQL or MariaDB support the `\u` encoding for string literals as you show. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html or https://mariadb.com/kb/en/string-literals/. This notation is not mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a database defined to use `CHARACTER SET utf8`and a `utf8_general_ci` collation it should just work like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `test` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
CREATE TABLE `test`.`sync_details` (`remoteData` MEDIUMTEXT);
INSERT INTO `test`.`sync_details` (`remoteData`) VALUES ('{"patientFirstName":"\\u0395\\u039b\\u0395\\u03a5\\u0398\\u0395\\u03a1\\u0399\\u039f\\u03a3"}');
SELECT `remoteData` FROM `test`.`sync_details` WHERE `remoteData` LIKE '%ΛΕΥΘΕΡ%';
+----------------------------------------------+
| remoteData                                   |
+----------------------------------------------+
| {"patientFirstName": "ΕΛΕΥΘΕΡΙΟΣ"}           |
+----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

You could also try `JSON_EXTRACT` to get structured data from the stored JSON object. I just tested it like this:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(`remoteData`, "$.patientFirstName") 
FROM `test`.`sync_details` 
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(`remoteData`, "$.patientFirstName") 
LIKE '%ΛΕΥΘΕΡ%';
+--------------------------------------------------+
| JSON_EXTRACT(`remoteData`, "$.patientFirstName") |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| "ΕΛΕΥΘΕΡΙΟΣ"                                     |
+--------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

To index data in the JSON object you could add a "Generated Column" to your table using the `GENERATED ALWAYS` syntax

```
ALTER TABLE `test`.`sync_details` ADD COLUMN `firstName` VARCHAR(100) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (`remoteData` ->> '$.patientFirstName');
CREATE INDEX `firstnames_idx` ON `test`.`sync_details`(`firstName`);
SELECT `firstName` FROM `test`.`sync_details` WHERE `firstName` LIKE '%ΛΕΥΘΕΡ%';
+----------------------+
| firstName            |
+----------------------+
| ΕΛΕΥΘΕΡΙΟΣ           |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

This will only work with MariaDB >= 10.2 and with a utf8 encoded db and a utf8_general_ci collation.

Comment: I get JSON_EXTRACT does not exists

Comment: Okay, JSON functions were added in MariaDB 10.2.3. Any chance to upgrade mariadb? Also, MariaDB 5.5 is EOL since April 2020.

Comment: I will see if it can be upgraded. But the table has some 150000 rows and rising. This way it will take to long. I was hopping to create a fulltext search index to have some optimization. Your query uses function upon the where clause and will ignore any indexes.